# is there a game studio for linux

Tags: 13.04, games

I've been looking for some time now for a good game studio. To make xbox and ps4 type games. Does some one know of some software that would work?

Comment: See: http://www.gamingonlinux.com/crowdfunding/index.php5?title=Game_Engines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Pygame.

Pygame is a set of Python modules designed for writing games. Pygame adds functionality on top of the excellent SDL library. This allows you to create fully featured games and multimedia programs in the python language. Pygame is highly portable and runs on nearly every platform and operating system.<sup>[Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html)</sup>

For more information, installation instructions, and to download, visit their [website](http://www.pygame.org/news.html).

Also take a look at [The Linux Game Studio](https://launchpad.net/linux-gs).

Comment: xbox, ps4... running python?

Comment: Pygame Uses optimized C, so it might work.

Comment: @BrunoPereira He said "[...] xbox and ps4 *type* games."